# Using Field Value in Correlated Sub Query within a Case Statement

Tags: sql

I am attempting to run a correlated subquery (instead of a join), taking the field of the outer query (jobs.employee) and to look that up in the employee_team table to return their Team (e.Team)

```
 select jobs.client_id, jobs.employee,
        Employee_Team = (select distinct e.Team from employee_teams as e where e.employee = jobs.employee)
        from jobs
```

However I am clearly doing something wrong as this returns the error

```
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression. I.e. i *think* it is returning all unique types of teams that exist in the e.Team field.
```

Where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An employee can be on more than one team.  Use `join`:

```
select j.client_id, j.employee, e.Team
from jobs j join
     employee_teams et
     on et.employee = j.employee;
```

Or to combine the results on one row, use aggregation.  Your error message looks like a SQL Server error message.  In that database, you would use `string_agg()`:

```
select j.client_id, j.employee, string_agg(e.Team, ', ') as teams
from jobs j join
     employee_teams et
     on et.employee = j.employee
group by j.client_id, j.employee;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only expect a one to one relationship you could add a TOP 1 :

```
select jobs.client_id, jobs.employee,
        Employee_Team = (select TOP 1 e.Team from employee_teams as e where e.employee = jobs.employee)
        from jobs
```

If there is a one to many relationship you will have to use a JOIN.